# MS Access VBA - How to save an Excel file; that is in a table, to a folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have saved an excel file into an Access database table.  The table has only 1 field named "file_template" and it is configured as an "Attachment" datatype.  I haven't used this datatype before so if it is not the best way to go, please point me in right direction.

This one file will be the only file in the table (so I am not worried about cycling thru table rows looking for specific filename to match)

When user opens the database I want the database to save a copy of the excel file to a specific folder within the users "Documents" folder.

I am drawing a blank on how to do this.  Any assist you all can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Below is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim strUser     As String
    Dim strPath     As String
    Dim strFilename     As String

    strUser = Environ("USERNAME")
    strPath = "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Documents\_template\"
    strFilename = "SomeExcelFile.xlsx"
        

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   That pointed me in the correct direction, and my code is working.   However, I do have an amendment to my initial question.  

Would you know how to overwrite the file if it already existed in the target folder?

Comment: Do you really need to overwrite or just use the file already in folder? Check if file exists with `If Dir(filepath\name) <> "" Then act accordingly`. Action could be `Kill filepath\name` to remove file.

Comment: Thank you for the response.   I will give the "kill" code a try.

Yes, the file that gets loaded to the folder is a template that is always in a state of being updated.  Overwriting will ensure that the user always has the latest version.